# Why do logs that are run by schedule:run on Laravel Vapor not saving in Cloudwatch?

Tags: laravel, amazon-cloudwatch, laravel-vapor

So I have this in my `Kernel.php` `$schedule->command('command:name')->hourly()->withoutOverlapping();` but it never stores the logs in Cloudwatch. However, if I run it manually using `vapor command staging --command="php artisan command:name"`, they do get stored in Cloudwatch.

I am assuming it has to do with cron based commands in Laravel Vapor storing their output to `/dev/null` but I might be wrong. My goal is to capture these logs, any help? To add further, my command basically fetches data from an API for 50 records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the official Laravel Vapor documentation:

> Log Messages
>
> Due to Vapor limitations, log messages from scheduled tasks will not
> appear in AWS CloudWatch or Vapor UI. As a workaround, you should
> dispatch a queued job from your scheduled tasks and write log messages
> from your queued job.

When you execute `vapor command staging --command="php artisan command:name` you are using the CLI. This mode generates logs and that's the reason you can see them.

Comment: Any ideas to get around this?

Answer (score -1):

Solved this by doing a symbolic link between the screen output and a log file. All thanks to [@koalaok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3248096/koalaok). See his answere here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46767123/4296706

```
ln -sf /proc/1/fd/1 /var/log/laravel-scheduler.log
```

and in my `Kernel.php`

```
$filePath = '/var/log/laravel-scheduler.log';;
$schedule->command('my sample command')->daily()->appendOutputTo($filePath);
```